Large Diameter BLDC motor lacking RPMs
I've recently acquired two outrunner motors from LG washing machines to put in my kid's go-kart. It's essentially this motor - a 36N48P outrunner motor with an 11" diameter rotor. These are wound with aluminum wire, 1 strand in hand, and have 96 turns per tooth. The rotor looks like it only has 12 poles, but I used a piece of magnet viewing paper and discovered that each magnet was technically 4 magnetic poles.
I changed the windings to 20T per tooth, and with both my custom VESC ESC and my APD 120F3[X] ESC at 48V, I cannot get this to spin any faster than about 100 to 150 RPM max. I'm running it in FOC mode. A friend tried running it with hall sensors on his setup but had the same issue. I can load the motor and the ESC does a decent job of maintaining the RPMs to the limit of the power supply.
I'm looking to get at least 1000RPM, maybe 1500RPM from it, but no matter what I do I can't seem to increase the motor speed. What am I missing?
Edit: I'm aware that this motor is in wye configuration, I'd like to keep it that way. I've seen people spin this motor using a VFD, and it has spun up to 1100-1500RPM

Have you tried field weakening? Or a higher voltage? Maybe the KV is just that low?

Your motor came from a mains washing machine that rotates at a sedate speed for quiet long term operation. So you have pulled turns off but then you are running 48VDC understandably for safety reasons. Well more turns must come off. If you use copper wire the losses will be lower. The Al wire was used for cost reasons not performance reasons. Use heavy wire with a similiar occupation ratio for good performance. You can use multiple strands of smaller dia wire in parallel if it wakes it easier to pack the winding tightly.  remember that the heavy wire fewer turns low voltage setup will mean more current for your drive electronics.

(The motor may be intended to spin laundry at 1600 rpm, too).

@Autistic, thanks for the feedback. considering the original turns on the motor, this equated to just shy of a volt per turn (85V RMS as the drive voltage). I dropped it to 20 turns, but I wasn't sure if the turns ratio was the only factor. I unwound it and am planning to rewind it this week with 6 turns per tooth, 12 strands in hand. This is just for experimentation at this point. No load on it yet. I have wire ordered, hoping to have it in soon.

@greybeard - you're correct. The driver for this I believe is higher voltage. I presumed 84V, but I'm also seeing that some of these motors drive at 300V. There's probably a boost converter involved somewhere which means it's probably only pulling 1-2 Amps.

Consider using one of the many golf cart motors available. It can be as simple as a series DC motor and controller or up to one of the three-phase induction motors/ 600 amp controller with 32 HP peak and 8 HP continuously on a 48-volt battery. Buy an old 36-volt golf cart. You only need the motor, controller, and differential transmission. Strip them out and use whatever you can in your kid's cart.
One of the older series DC motors with a 100-amp controller and a transmission with smaller wheels gives you a 10—to 15 mph Go-Kart. You can go really fast; you are only limited by money. I have made a few racing golf carts. With off-the-shelf parts, 0-70 in 4 seconds or top speeds in excess of 100 mph are possible.

I appreciate the feedback, but this does not at all address what I posted.  I can easily get a golf cart motor setup, but I'm trying to build up THIS motor. It's a project, I understand, I was looking for feedback on how to make it work.
